# php mysql and login not working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

i am creating a login page using php and mysql but  after enter the email and password and submit the inputs  the browser display a blank page without going to the profile page .

how to fix this error???

## login.php

```
    <?php
    $message = ""; 
    if(isset($_POST['email'])!="")
    {
    require_once('include/connect.php');
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $pass = strip_tags($pass);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($pass);
    //$pass = md5($pass);
    $firstname="";
    $email="";
    $sql=mysql_query( "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE email_address='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1") or die("error in user table");
    $login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);

      if($login_check > 0)
      {
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
          {
              $id = $row['user_id'];
              $_SESSION['user_id']= $id;
              var_dump($id);
              $firstname = $row['first_name'];
              $_SESSION['first_name']= $firstname;
              var_dump($firstname);
              $email = $row['email'];
              $_SESSION['email']= $email;
              var_dump($email);
              mysql_query("UPDATE user SET last_log_date=now() WHERE user_id='$id'");

              header("Location: profile.php");    

          }//close while

      }//close if 
      else
      {
          $message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
          exit();
      }
    }//close if

    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>RegisterPage</title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Satisfy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

</head>

<body>


       <div id="loginborder">
         <p  style="color:#FF0000" align="left"><?php print("$message") ?></p>

         <!--Login form where user submit his registered email and password-->
         <form action="login.php" method="post">
           email-address:<br />
           <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Adress" />
           <br />
           <br />
           Password:<br />
           <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
           <br />
           <br />
           <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
           <a href="register.php" style="position: absolute; top: 132px; left: 61px;"> <strong> Register</strong></a>
         </form>
       </div>
       <br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

      <div id="footer-bg">
    <div id="footer-content" class="container">

        <div id="column3">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            <ul class="style1">
                <li class="first">Lam El Chamel is the first web development  system for me, this system had allow me to expand my knowledge and had put me in the first step of the programming career.

           Hope that this system will respnd for user's requirements, and as each system it will have a future enhancment with taking into consideration users feedback in the feedback section.
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <div id="column4">
            <h2>Navigation</h2>
            <ul class="style1">
                <li class="first"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="container">
    <p>Copyright (c) 2013 Lam_El_Chamel.zxq.net All rights reserved. Design by Georges Matta.
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A blank page is often indicative of a syntax error, or a fatal error that isn't being displayed because error reporting is turned off. Are you sure it's turned on?

Comment: how to turn on the error reporting ???

Comment: Use if(!empty($_POST['email'])) instead of if(isset($_POST['email'])!="")

Comment: To turn on error reporting in this script only, add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the top of your script after `<?php`. To turn it on globally, find and modify the setting in your php.ini configuration file and restart your web server.

Comment: still not working  and after submit the login in the URL it display localhost /name of file/login.php

Answer (score 0):

Your login might be failing at

```
if($login_check > 0)
```

and executing else part

```
 $message = "incorrect Email or Password!!";
 exit();
```

Just echo your `$message` variable before `exit()`

Comment: the error was the exit();   but now i got another error that the system display that the username and password are incorrect

Comment: the answer : delete the **$firstname=""; $email="";**
because the system was returnd the post **email and password  = empty.**
so that it display that the incorrect email or password

Comment: ok. now echo your query
`echo "SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE email_address='$email'AND password='$pass'LIMIT 1"` before executing `$sql=mysql_query(..` line & then run tht query manually in phpmyadmin & check whether you are passing right parameters or not